# Writing .txt infront of the first column

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a text file like this

```
E13,E16,ES,2738
E12,E13,EM,394
E5,E5,E6,354
```

I want to delete the first two columns and want to write `.txt` with the 3rd column , i wrote the following code for it

```
import csv
with open("num2_try.txt","rb") as source:
    rdr= csv.reader( source )
    with open("result.txt","wb") as result:
        wtr= csv.writer( result )
        for r in rdr:
            wtr.writerow( (r[2],r[3]) )
```

It give me the output like this

```
ES,2738
EM,394
E6,354
```

But i want something like this

```
ES.txt 2738
EM.txt 394
E6.txt 354
```

Comment: Delete the first two *columns* perhaps?

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes , i edit it

Comment: You can use `with open('input', 'rb') as src, open('output', 'wb') as res:` to keep your nesting down a level...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.txt` to your `r[2]` string:

```
wtr.writerow((r[2] + '.txt', r[3]))
```

If you wanted to use spaces for delimiters instead of commas, configure your `csv.writer()` to use a different delimiter:

```
wtr = csv.writer(result, delimiter=' ')
```